# Accidental Serial-Voting, What Happens?

Tags: support, voting, serial-voting

I was trying to get `Civic Duty` and try to improve the standards of a good post by voting (a lot). Got Suffrage and Vox Populi, blah blah blah, then I saw the "crime" I have committed: Serial Voting. WAHHHHH! But wait. I have never really pay attention to who I am voting on unless it is someone like Jon Skeet from SO or fredley from Coffee. Here is the page on newest questions on which I voted on: https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions 
 This might change, but if you notice, lots of users are actually writing questions repeatedly within seconds/minutes. Looking at [fredley's](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/users/127/fredley) user page, I voted nearly all his votes... With upvotes. 

So I have accidently serial voted. Will I get in trouble, and will my votes get banned for ***accidental*** serial voting?

Comment: It was nice knowing you.

Comment: UHHH, why would you say that. Do you think I'm suspended right now?

Comment: Just how many posts are we talking here, and during what amount of time? You should never, by the way, just cast votes to get a badge. In general, doing things *just to get a badge* is unacceptable.

Comment: @HDE 226868, as you can see, that was my not my main reason. It was mostly to improve the quality of the posts with the motivation of Civic Duty, that's all

Comment: @Sabre Tooth, this serial voting stuff, I already know. What I don't know is what happens if you serial vote on accident, not on purpose.

Comment: @SabreTooth It's not a duplicate, he's asking about if he accidentally serially votes.

Comment: When I first joined the site years ago, I had an answer answered by Jon Skeet. I thought his other answers were so great that I upvoted them as well. I didn't know that it was against the rules. Sorry Jon :( I am fairly certain a majority of them were removed, but no action was taken against my account as it was just a one time mistake by a new user. Long story short, you should be fine but you should also avoid any voting irregularities in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magic that goes on in the Stack Exchange servers don't really care for your [*mens rea*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mens_rea). They'll do their thing and, yes, if it fit the criteria for invalidation, your votes will be invalidated.

But fear not, vote invalidation has no lasting impact against you. Suspensions occur manually, and assuming a moderator doesn't see anything to make him or her believe that you had malice, you'll be fine.

The worst case, probably, would be receiving a Moderator Message with a suspension of a few days. But realistically, for a first offense without any evidence of revenge or anything, even that would be overkill and quite unlikely, and explaining yourself would get it lifted pretty quickly.

I've dealt with a few voting sprees during my time as moderator, and honestly I've yet to issue a suspension, even in cases of actual targeted voting. The job of moderation teams is to keep sites healthy, active, and fun for all. So in cases where users try to cheat the system, we'll intervene and stop that via suspensions. But in cases where someone accidentally tried to show too much appreciation to a certain user and shows no other signs of destruction, simply leveling the playing field with some vote invalidation is sufficient to maintain our mission.

Comment: "no lasting impact" isn't entirely accurate. The account has a permanent record of the voting irregularity. I agree though that for this *one* instance there should be no action taken which would be noticeable to the OP.